# Codeigniter pagination - display without last record

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I have been searching for long time but I'm new in CI so it's really hard to find the answer.

So here is the problem: I want to get all of my records without the last one from the database using CI pagination ... I know that I need to do something with my model but I don't know what :/ This is how it looks like:

```
public function get_results($search_term = 'default', $offset = 0, $limit = 0) {

    $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,blog_time,blog_title,blog_text,image', false);
    $this->db->from('blog');
    $this->db->like('blog_title', $search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('blog_text', $search_term);
    $this->db->order_by('blog_time', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    $data = $this->db->get()->result();
    $count = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() count;')->row()->count;
    return array('data' => $data, 'count' => $count);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the Model code to this:

```
public function get_results($search_term = 'default', $offset = 0, $limit = 0) {

    $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,blog_time,blog_title,blog_text,image', false);
    $this->db->from('blog');
    $this->db->like('blog_title', $search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('blog_text', $search_term);
    $this->db->order_by('blog_time', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    $data = $this->db->get()->result();
    $count = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() count;')->row()->count;
    return array('data' => $data, 'count' => $count -1);
}
```

We simply added -1 to the $count.

Comment: Hmmm .. this make sense but still not working :( I`m using this in my controller $config['total_rows'] = $data['records']['count']; but ['count'] still returns to me all of my records ...

Comment: Wait .. i just var_dump $data['records']['count']; and it returns 20 records .. not 21 , as i want to hmm there is something that i miss .

Comment: var_dump return the correct amount but where is the problem?

Comment: Still don`t know . Pagination get 20 results but displaying 21 :@

Comment: Try to set $count to -5 for example see if the Pagination change?

Comment: Do you have teamviewer? I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

you can use the unset function of php

for your result

```
unset($result[0]);
```

as you are using descending last record will come first

and in your count

```
$count = $count-1;
```